# jetty with spring MVC session.isNew() returns always false

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jetty

I am running Jetty 9.3 with Spring MVC and Spring Security. My main page is intercepted by Spring Security Login page which is in JSP. The problem is with my *SessionTimeoutIntercepter* which should redirect in case of session timeout. What I want to do when the session is timed out - redirect to Spring Security Login page with some parameter like "Session expired". The problem is that *session.isNew()* which I use always returns false((( I tried with mapping to *"/**"* - the same result. Even after my first request to server and login page - this function returns false((( Can somebody help me why?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that some people may do something like

```
Session session = request.getSession();
if(session.isNew()) {
    //doSmth
}
```

but method getSession() return new session if it not exists yet. You need getSession(false) - it don't create new session, just return null if it doesn't exists or return old session with timeout expired.
In your case, you can add some logic to interceptor

```
Session session = request.getSession(false);
if(session == null || session.isNew() {
    // do redirect
}
```